# Restrict mouse from moving to secondary monitor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, mouse

I have two screens connected to my system and I am working in Ubuntu Linux. Is it possible to make the mouse work only on one screen and to make it stop going in the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this from a similar question:

The trick is to separate the 2 screen by a virtual space in xorg.conf , then use a tool called mouse-switchscreen to "jump" between the screens.

My config: Ubuntu 10.04 x64, ATI Mobility RadeonHD , ATI Catalyst Control Center correctly installed, screens in mode "Single Display Desktop" (each screen has it's own Desktop)

These are the steps that I made:

1. Download dualscreen-mouse-utils from

   - [http://digamma.cs.unm.edu/trac.dmohr/wiki/DualscreenMouseUtils](https://web.archive.org/web/20091024041751/http://digamma.cs.unm.edu/trac.dmohr/wiki/DualscreenMouseUtils)
2. Decompress the package, in terminal type: make , you may need to xorg-dev package (in Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install xorg-dev` )
3. Copy the mouse-switchscreen binary to folder included in PATH (I used `/usr/bin`)
4. Start gconf-editor (Alt-F2), in apps\metacity\keybinding_commands choose an empty command, and add: **`mouse-switchscreen -f 1`**
5. In gconf-editor apps\metacity\global_keybindings choose the same number for run_command_n and add a shortcut of your choice, personally I entered: `<Super>Tab =Win+Tab`
6. If everything is working, Edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (better make a backup before), in the "ServerLayout" section, change the position of a screen to make the two separate. ONE pixel is enough :D

You can now `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart` and enjoy. Of course, Win+Tab to switch the screen. You can also try mouse-wrapscreen, mouse-wrapscreen -h for more info.

All credits goes to: David Antliff & David Mohr for mouse-switchscreen, and the Linux community for the infos.

Comment: The download link for dualscreen-mouse-utils is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Jared for sharing his solution](https://superuser.com/a/485515/167207), which may help others find their own.

I've found that the original links to the named tool are dead, and have found some open and accessible alternatives for this.

Essentially, I took what Jared said about leaving virtual space in between the two displays and came up with another solution to moving the mouse between the two displays.

1. Setup virtual space between two outputs with xorg config or xrandr

   - `xrandr --output Output-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0`
   - `xrandr --output Output-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 2000x0`
   - The above example leaves 80 width of virtual space between the two outputs
2. Move your mouse between displays using `xdotool`

   - `xdotool mousemove 2000 0` moves the mouse to position 2000x0, which is the right-hand display configured with xrandr previously
   - `xdotool mousemove 0 0` moves the mouse to position 0x0, which is the left-hand display configured with xrandr previously
3. Use `xdotool` within `sxhkd` hotkeys for quick switching