# Block mouse from secondary monitor

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, mouse

How can I prevent the mouse from entering a secondary monitor, in Windows 7?

I want to restrict mouse movement to be only within the primary monitor.

Ideally I would also like to prevent accidentally moving any windows to the second monitor, or shifting input focus to it in any way.

The second monitor should only be used to display the full-screen window of a specific application.

There does not need to be any way to interact with that application, and ideally there should be no way to do so accidentally.

How can I restrict the mouse to a single monitor?

*(There is a related question for Linux [here](https://superuser.com/questions/485510/restrict-mouse-from-moving-to-secondary-monitor), this question is about Windows 7)*

Comment: What have you researched or tried so far? Is this related to a specific application?

Comment: I have tried rearranging monitors in the windows system settings, but the best I could get was two monitors arranged 'over-edge', one in the lower-left corner and one in the upper-right corner, which still allows the mouse to slip to the second monitor. I have not found any other method of restricting mouse movement to a specific monitor

Comment: I don't think Windows will be able to do what you need without any help. Have you done an Internet search? I found [Mouse Trapper](http://download.cnet.com/Mouse-Trapper/3000-2317_4-75878300.html) on CNET pretty quickly. There are surely many solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed this was possible through some registry setting or similar, since the information about which edge of one monitor connects to which other edge must be stored *somewhere*. If an external tool is indeed required, then I suppose this is the wrong place for this question, probably better asked on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com